# Javascript HashMap to Visualforce Remoting Method

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, map, object

Can we pass HashMap from Javascript to controller? Where aMap['a123']=['xy','yz']; and aMap['b456']=['ab','bc'];
I want a remote action method with Map> parameter in controller.

Comment: Referring to this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9934/javascript-remoting-with-set-collection/72189

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

For your JS,

```
var aMap = {};
aMap['b456']=['ab','bc'];
aMap['a123']=['xy','yz'];
```

your remote method would need to look like this:

```
public PageReference doSometing(Map<String,List<String>>) {
    return null;
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @jeremy ! The Remote Method does not work using argument as Map<String,List<String>> but it takes the array as a string, so had to use Map<String,String> but this is not what i was expecting.

Comment: the lesson here: never assume -- i was sure I had done map<str,list> before.  Probably just maps of simple types, tho'.  i will say that you could put a custom class in the signature -- it seems as though I've had lists as properties in a custom class -- i don't recall if it was a public Pageref, or a remoteAction tho'.  worst case, you can always json serialize something and just have a string as the single method parameter.

glad you got something working!